# Ansible fire a bash file, forget and return terminal

Tags: bash, ansible

`mybash.sh` calls a python program that should run forever(theoretically).  This means *async time limit* should be infinity. But using the following ansible lines, it stop after the time limit, in this case *45*. If I remove `async: 45`, execution of ansible never return in terminal as the python program run continuously.

```
  - name: fire and forget
    command: sh mybash.sh
    async: 45
    poll: 0
```

How do I make the ansible to fire, forget and return execution of ansible in terminal (i.e this python program called by mybash.sh will run forever and execution of ansible in terminal should not wait)?

Comment: This is really a bad practice. You should be using ansible to configure a service instead.

Comment: Also, `sh` is not bash. If you start it with `sh`, it's a POSIX sh script, not a bash script.

Comment: ...now, if you *do* want a program to detach from the process that started it and run in the background, the verb for what you want it to do is "daemonize" itself, and there will be lots of search results for that -- but self-daemonizing programs/scripts are bad practice; it's much, *much* better to use a process supervision system your operating system provides (which will let you configure it to start on boot; can manage restarting after failures; etc).

Answer (score 0):

If that's really what you want to do instead of configuring a service, you could do something like:

```
- name: fire and forget
  shell: nohup mybash.sh &
```

Since you're going to use it, you might want to look at the [manpage to nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup).

Comment: Strongly recommend at least redirecting stdout/stderr explicitly so as not to be leaving a `nohup.out` around somewhere. (Personally, I tend to see nohup as unnecessary silliness -- doesn't do anything you couldn't do from native bash with `disown`, `exec >/dev/null 2>&1` and a `trap` command to clear the default behavior for `HUP` -- but... *shrug*)

Comment: `nohup` seems very odd to use from inside of ansible.